# Progress of UIprogress view on a label in swift3

Tags: xcode, swift3, ios10

I am trying to display the progress of the `progressview` in `swift3` on a label using the following code but the progress gets stuck on 10% and doesn't proceeds further.
Please HELP!!!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


   Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(myprogressview),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func myprogressview(timer : Timer)
{

    var count : Int = 0
    count += 1

    if (count <= 10)
    {
        Progress1.progress = Float(count)/10.0
        progressLabel.text = String.init(format: "%d %%", count*10)

    }

    timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: You invalidate (stop) the timer in the main body of 'myprogressview' so it will never get past the first time you call it so it stops at 1 out of 10 (10%). You want to invalidate the timer only when 'count==10'.  Also 'count' will be reset to 0 every time because it is a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to invalidate the timer in else condition because when function call first time timer invalidate  and declaration of count outside the `myprogressview()` function because each time it become zero

```
 var count : Int = 0
    func myprogressview(timer : Timer)
    {
        count += 1

        if (count <= 10)
        {
            print(count*10)
            progress.progress = Float(count)/10.0
            progressLable.text = String.init(format: "%d %%", count*10)

        } else {

         timer.invalidate()
        }


    }
```